# Wget and utf-8 website

Tags: utf-8, wget

I want to download my own website as simple html (http://www.dariomac.com) with wget to make an offline portfolio. My problem is that wget download all the website correctly but some characters are saved incorrectly. For example, my name, Darío Macchi is saved as DarÃ­o Macchi.

Are there any way to solve this problem? if no, are there other software to use in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: my OS is Windows with NTFS file system

Comment: what is your OS and filesystem type?

Comment: You need unicode wget. No idea where from.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/233882/how-to-download-link-with-unicode-using-wget